# Delegate function not called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-protocols

I have two view controllers (**ViewController** and **ActionViewController**) and one manager (**Brain**), the second view controller is shown when a user tapped on a button by a show segue created in storyboard and to get back to the first I use a self.dismiss in the second view controller.

The user enter a number on **ActionViewController** that need to be retrieved in **ViewController**. So I created **Brain** to use the delegate pattern.

The problem is that the delegate function inside **ViewController** is never run, I read other SO answers but nothing work. I used print statement to know where the code is not running anymore and the only block not running is the didUpdatePrice inside **ViewController**

Here is the code

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, BrainDelegate {

    var brain = Brain()

    @IBOutlet var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        brain.delegate = self
        
        scoreLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        scoreLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    func didUpdateScore(newScore: String) {
        
    
        print("the new label is \(newScore)")
        
        scoreLabel.text = newScore
    }
}
```

**ActionViewController**

```
class ActionViewController: UIViewController {

    var brain = Brain()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        brain.newAction(actualScore: 0, newActionValue: 5, isPositive: true)
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
        
    }
        
}
```

**Brain**

```
protocol BrainDelegate {
    func didUpdateScore(newScore: String)
}

struct Brain {
    
    var delegate: BrainDelegate?
    
    func newAction(actualScore: Int, newActionValue: Int, isPositive: Bool) {
        
        let newScore: Int
        
        if isPositive {
            
            newScore = actualScore + newActionValue
            
            
        } else {
            
            newScore = actualScore - newActionValue
        }
        
        print("the new score is \(newScore)")
        
        delegate?.didUpdateScore(newScore: String(newScore))
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need an additional `Brain` class/struct at all, You can achieve it with simple protocol and default extension of protocol.

**Step 1:** Select your show segue and provide an identifier to that in storyboard as shown below

[image]

**Step 2:** In your ViewController add `prepare(for segue` method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "testIdentifier" {
            guard let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? ActionViewController else { return }
            destinationViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }
```

**Step 3:** In your `ActionViewController` declare a weak property named `delegate`

```
class ActionViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: BrainDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.newAction(actualScore: 0, newActionValue: 5, isPositive: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true)

    }

}
```

**Step 4:** Add `class` clause to your `BrainDelegate` (Class bound protocol) so that you can hold a weak reference to delegate

```
protocol BrainDelegate: class {
    func didUpdateScore(newScore: String)
    func newAction(actualScore: Int, newActionValue: Int, isPositive: Bool)
}
```

**Step 5:**

Add a default extension to `BrainDelegate` and provide default implementation of `newAction(actualScore:`

```
extension BrainDelegate {
    func newAction(actualScore: Int, newActionValue: Int, isPositive: Bool) {
        let newScore: Int

        if isPositive {
            newScore = actualScore + newActionValue
        } else {
            newScore = actualScore - newActionValue
        }

        print("the new score is \(newScore)")
        self.didUpdateScore(newScore: String(newScore))
    }
}
```

**Step 6:** In your `ActionViewController` simply trigger delegate methods as

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.newAction(actualScore: 0, newActionValue: 5, isPositive: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

This should do the job

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for now the code doesn't compile, it gave me this error ' Non-'@objc' method 'newAction(actualScore:newActionValue:isPositive:)' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'BrainDelegate' ' i tried to add @objc annotation to the default extension of newAction but it's not working

Comment: have you added `@objc` extension to protocol declaration? `@objc protocol BrainDelegate` ?

Comment: yes I added the @objc annotation before the protocol declaration and it's the only place where I've used it

Comment: @dadamatteo: Ohhh got it, gimme a minute lemme update the answer

Comment: @dadamatteo: I have updated my answer please read whole answer again, all you have to do is change `@objc protocol BrainDelegate` to `protocol BrainDelegate: class` remove all `@objc` annotation from your code, follow the answer properly checked the code, its compiling and working fine

Comment: yes it's perfect everything is working fine, gonna mark it as the answer thanks mate

Comment: @dadamatteo: am glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

First, on `Brain` you should use class, not struct. That is because when you use struct, passing the variable to another will make a copy, it will not use the same reference. And class will only copy the reference.

That means that your `Brain` struct will lose the delegate assigned on `.delegate = self`

second, you need to use the same instance on the second viewController and the first. like this:

on the first viewController

```
var brain = Brain()
// this one is the one that you will put your "brain.delegate = self"
```

on the second viewController, you will need to inject this variable from the first viewController into the second. That is to keep the same instance on both. And this will make the delegate callable.

to do this with storyboard you will do on the first ViewController:

```
// this function should be called when the next viewController should open. 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch segue.destination) {
        case let vc as MyViewController:
            vc.brain = self.brain
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
}
```

inside the second viewController, use:

```
var brain: Brain?
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get my error with the struct/class thing, and I understand why I need the same instance of Brain on the two ViewControllers but how can I inject the variable as I transition between the two via a storyboard segue?

Comment: I updated my answer, oh, for segue, just a moment.

Comment: ok thanks and for the second viewController ?

Comment: it is just to declare the variable there, and then you can call it on the second wherever you want.